# add color property to form_error

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I would like to add **css** of my errors in **Symfony**. When I am creating a form, I am detecting errors using annotations in my entity classes and adding **form_error(form.field)** in my **html.twig** file. I would like to give a color of this errors. Here is my code:

```
        {{ form_label(form.name , 'name') }}
        {{ form_widget(form.name, {'attr': {'placeholder': 'Name','class': 'form-control'} }) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.name) }}
```

I would like to add **attr** to my **form_errors** to specify that the color I want to use is red. The errors are generated like this:

```
class hello {
/**
  * @Assert\NotBlank()
  * @Assert\Regex(
  *     pattern="/\d/",
  *     match=false,
  *     message="Your name should not contain numbers"
  * )
  */
     private $name;
  }
```

The error generated is Your name should not contain numbers but it's color is **black** not **red**.
Thanks

Comment: It's possible to see your form template ?

Comment: ok @AL.coolique

Comment: @ysd But what is wrong with adding class to it and change color of it with css?

Comment: @Sebastian the problem is that when I see the source code, I got that form_error is equivalent to <ul> so I don't see how to specify this <ul>. do you see what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how looks your twig for render this form.

But you can try this:

```
 <div class="form-group {% if form.email.vars.errors|length > 0 %}has-error{% endif %}">
```

This adds `has-error` class if any error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a [form theme](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#what-are-form-themes)
- [Modify `form_errors`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#form-fragment-naming) inside your theme in order to take what you've passed along your field option (use `attr` option for the field, so you don't have to define your own option)
- Apply the theme where you need it (or set it as [global theme](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#global-form-theming))

I'm sorry if this answer is a bit "abstract" but without any line of code is way to difficult to be more concrete.

Comment: @ysd that's not enough: if you follow my points and if you study symfony, I bet you can reach what you want :)

Comment: @ysd my last comment is because that's not the right code - or amount of it - necessary to tackle the issue. Moreover, here on SO, question should be "general" and not adherent to a particular OP case.